# Why press the stop debugging button during a debugging session crashes the host?

Tags: zerobrane

I've successfully managed to implement ZBS to debug the scripting code of a  C++ real time game.  It works really great!

However, there is still an issue that I don't know how to solve:  if I press the stop debugging button or menu option during a debugging session, my C++ host program crashes.

Would you please give me ideas of why this could be happening?

Thanks a lot in advance,
kind regards,

Mauricio.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stopping debugging calls `os.exit(1, true)` by default, so you will need to check if the resources are correctly released in this case. If you want to provide your own handler, you can do it by setting `require('mobdebug').onexit = function() --[[your exit handler]] end` in your application.

Comment: Thanks!  I just added: 
`debug.onexit = debug.done`
and it worked great!

Comment: This should work, but notice that in this case the debugger disconnects, but the application continues its execution without any debugging.